# Brackets showing after reading txt file and inserting into text widget. any way of simple fix?

Tags: python, tkinter, textbox, save, curly-braces

I am making a simple note-taking app. i want to save the contents of the entry box, save it to a txt file and when the program is next loaded, i want the box to read the file and contain the data. it works apart from the annoying brackets that appear in the text box. the brackets are not in the txt file. any help would be appreciated. (Sorry I use pretty random variable names)

```
import tkinter as tk
import os
from os import system

root=tk.Tk()

def yes():
    charm = death.get("1.0", tk.END)
    if (os.path.exists('charm.txt')):
        moder = open('charm.txt','w')
        moder.write(charm)
        moder.close()
    else:
        moder = open('charm.txt','w+')
        moder.write(charm)
        moder.close()
        
    print(charm)

death=tk.Text(root, height=5, width=50)
death.pack()

save=tk.Button(root, text='save', command = yes)
save.pack()

if (os.path.exists('charm.txt')):
    drug = open('charm.txt','r')
    note = (drug.readlines())
    drug.close()
    note = str(note)
    print(note)
    death.insert("1.0" ,note)

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: @TheLizzard Does not change anything, as the parenthesis can, and should be omitted.

Comment: @NameKhan72 my bad

Comment: @POVEY Also please correct if I am wrong but I don't think you need the `if (os.path.exists('charm.txt'))` and the `open('charm.txt','w+')` because `open` will automatically create the file if it doesn't exits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
note = (drug.readlines())
```

To:

```
note = drug.read()
```

This will fix your problem, as readlines() returns a list.

Comment: Thank you mate. I am an idiot for not realising this!